# Confirm Send and Receiving SMS in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

A message (SMS) had been sent from our application and I need to capture the return message as well. As I understand iOS does not give the permission to read SMS messages but Android does. So how can I do it through Xamarin Forms? I found Xam.Plugins that help me to send the text message only but I need to handle the return as well.

Is it possible to confirm if the user does actually hit the send button since the API will redirect the user from our application to message application so can count the action also?

Thanks in advance.

-BB

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand iOS does not give the permission to read SMS messages but Android does. So how can I do it through Xamarin Forms?

If it is not supported in iOS, then you cannot achieve this by building a Xamarin Forms app. Xamarin Forms is only a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to easily create native user interface layouts that can be shared across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone.

> I found Xam.Plugins that help me to send the text message only but I need to handle the return as well.

I think there is no need to repeat that it is not supported in iOS, then here I only explain how to achieve this in Android: using `BroadcastReceiver`, and since you're developing an Xamarin.Forms app, this work should be done in the Android project of your forms app, the code can't be shared on other platforms.

For the sample, you can refer to this blog: [Read SMS Automatically using Broadcast Receivers In Android Xamarin](http://developersupdates.blogspot.sg/2015/10/broadcast-receivers-in-android-xamarin.html).

> Is it possible to confirm if the user does actually hit the send button since the API will redirect the user from our application to message application so can count the action also?

For this question, you can refer to the discussion in xamarin's official forum here: [Sending sms and display Toast when message is sent and/or delivered](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11889/sending-sms-and-display-toast-when-message-is-sent-and-or-delivered).